# ReactJS, material UI setStates after additional button

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick, datapicker

I have data picker from material UI and simply function that update state on data from data picker. But I need do it in two steps: first data picket get data, and next after additional button clicked states are update. Or after click this button props are push to child. I try to find it, but reactJS is still a little complicate for me. Please, help me.

This is my code:

```
var DataPickerField = React.createClass({

 getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      toInsert: ''
    };
  },

  setFechaDesde(e,data){
        this.setState({
          toInsert: data
        })
},

  render: function(){
    console.log(this.state.toInsert);
    return(
      <div>
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <DatePicker
                hintText = "Wybierz datę"
                onChange={(e, data) => this.setFechaDesde(e,data)}
                defaultDate={new Date()}
            />

        </MuiThemeProvider>
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <RaisedButton label="OK" />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
        <Insert valToInsert = {this.state.toInsert} />
    </div>)
}
})

module.exports=DataPickerField;
```

Comment: can you also write your setFechaDesde function?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figure it out. Button should be in child component. Then I can use it to do the rest of my code that need state from parent. It's not exacly what I wanted, but it,s exacly what I should to do.  Sorry for problem